# Java8 reducing a stream

Tags: java, java-8, lambda, java-stream

I have the following methods:

```
static IntStream streamedDivisors(final int n) {
    return IntStream.range(2, n).parallel().filter(input -> n % input == 0);
}

static int streamedPhi(final int n) {
    return streamedDivisors(n).reduce(0, x -> x * x);
}
```

and I'm getting a compilation error in streamedPhi indicating that I have incompatible parameter types in my lambda expression.  Can someone help me make sense of this?  I'm essentially trying to take the divisors of a given number n, and aggregate a number on some function I defined (in this case, squaring the number).

Comment: If you want the sum of the squares, this is a mapping *and* a reduction (accumulation).  You've specified the mapping function, but in the wrong place.  And you haven't specified your accumulation function at all!  You probably want: streamedDivisors(n).map(x -> x*x).sum(), or some other reduction besides sum.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out later.  And to be corrected by you is both an honor, and embarrassing :)  Seriously, I'm a big fan @BrianGoetz!  Your book is required reading at Workday

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your compilation issue is due to the fact that [`IntBinaryOperator#applyAsInt(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntBinaryOperator.html#applyAsInt-int-int-) takes two arguments. You were only declaring/providing one.

As stated in the comments and after looking at the javadoc of [`IntStream#reduce(int, IntBinaryOperator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#reduce-int-java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator-) , you aren't actually applying a valid reduction. It's not immediately clear to me what you mean by *and aggregate a number on some function I defined* but [Brian has some suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964639/java8-reducing-a-stream/23964689?noredirect=1#comment36932993_23964639).

Comment: Thats strange.  Why would it require two arguments exactly?  Wouldn't var args be more suitable?

Comment: @AmirAfghani It's a _binary_ operator. 2.

Comment: I see I'm missing something.  I understand the meaning of binary - however - why is it a binary operator?  All I've said is stream the divisors and do a sum += operation on them.  What does the other input represent exactly?

Comment: Does the y value represent the accumulator value?

Comment: @AmirAfghani The javadoc of `reduce` shows the equivalent code and what it's meant to do. `y` seems to be each value in the stream. `x` is the accumulation.

Comment: The function you've specified in this answer, which ignores the right argument, isn't a valid reduction function, because its not associative.

Comment: @BrianGoetz I wanted to demonstrate why to the compilation error occurred. Please feel free to add to the answer.